# Babel Register not transpiling own files included within node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to use [`alexa-app-server`](https://github.com/alexa-js/alexa-app-server) with some code that I have written in ES6 that needs to be transpiled. When I run my own server, I would like to not have to transpile separately ahead of time and just include the file `server.js`:

```
require("babel-register")({ignore: false, presets: ["es2015"]});
const AlexaAppServer = require("alexa-app-server");
AlexaAppServer.start({
    port: process.env.PORT || 8080,
    app_dir: "apps",
});
```

Then I have `apps/skill/index.js` with:

```
import alexa from "alexa-app";
const skill = new alexa.app("skill");
skill.launch((req, res) => res.say("hello"));
skill.intent("TestIntent", ["test"], (req, res) => res.say("test"));

export const express = skill.express;
```

The `express` export is for when alexa-app-server requires the file: https://github.com/alexa-js/alexa-app-server/blob/master/index.js#L68

When I run my server code, I get:

> ```
> Error loading app [/Users/acrites/projects/mobq/usbank/functions/usbank/index.js]:
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
> ```

This indicates to me that the file is not being transpiled. `alexa-app-server` is in `node_modules`, but I am using `ignore: false` [as indicated in the babel documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babel-register/) to include `node_modules` but since the files that are included are not actually in `node_modules` I'm not even sure that this would be necessary. Using `babel-node server.js` does the same thing. Running `babel-node apps/skill` works fine, though.

Is there any way to get babel to transpile files that are themselves required within `node_modules`?